# How to count symbol in string and split accordingly and set in Textview?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i have a string in which i have to count symbol and split that string accordingly and set it in textview.

code:-

```
int commas = 0;
String data = "Note:MRP shown , rates.The tariff plans are subject to change .Plans have been provided for information purposes only.";
for (int i=0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    if (data.charAt(i) == ".") {
        commas++;
    }
}
```

Comment: for splitting java provides function have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481842/6869086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner you could use:

```
int commas = data.split("\\.").length - 1;
```

If you actually need to parse your text into separate sentences, you could do something similar:

```
String[] parts = data.split("\\.");
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    if (i > 0) text.append("\n");
    text.append(" * " + part[i] + ".");
}

TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
yourTextView.setSingleLine(false);
yourTextView.setText(text.toString());
```

Note here that I am using HTML inside the `TextView` to get newlines after each sentence.

Comment: but how to set it in Textview

Comment: But how to set it in textview because i have to set textview based on index at runtime

Comment: Because i dont know the index may be it may increase at runtime

Comment: Also i want to add * before every line of textview

Comment: It is working but it always set "Plans have been provided for information purposes only" in Textview

Comment: Sorry, let me edit this.  I could not test anything.  One minute.

Comment: sure take your time

Comment: I made another update, give it a try and leave feedback if necessary.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be happening.  What is the value of `text` in your code right before we add that the to the `TextView`?  Is it a string?

Comment: Another typo, use this instead: `text.append(" * " + part[i] + ".");` ... by the way, I'm not setup right now to easily test my code